# What will be the formula to find how many Fibonacci terms are there below a given no., $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fibonacci-numbers

So if I take a number, $n=10$,
$$f(n)=6$$
Because there are only 6 Fibonacci terms below it ($1,1,2,3,5,8$). So is there any formula for this?

Comment: This sequence appears to be [A130233](https://oeis.org/A130233) in the OEIS.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536810/42969.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the $k$th fibonacci number is 
$$
a_k = \frac{ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k }{\sqrt{5}}.
$$
which is very nearly equal to 
$$
b_k = \frac{ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  }{\sqrt{5}}.
$$
If $n = b_k$, then
$$
\ln(n) = k \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) - \ln(\sqrt{5})
$$
so 
$$
\ln(\sqrt{5}n)  = k \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) 
$$
so
$$
k = \frac{\ln(\sqrt{5}n)}{\ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) }
$$
So your answer is that for large $n$ (perhaps $20$ or so?) the number of fibonacci numbers less than or equal to $n$ is (very nearly) 
$$
k = \left\lfloor \frac{\ln(\sqrt{5}n)}{\ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) } \right\rfloor
$$

If you want the exact value, you can use this estimate of $k$, and then compute the $k-1$st, $k$th, and $k+1$st Fibonacci numbers (using the first formula) and then see which ones are less than $n$, and you'll have your answer.

A reasonably practical alternative is to start with *twice* the estimated value I've given for $k$, and then perform a binary search to find the largest $i$ for which $a_i < n$. Since you'll be computing powers of $\phi$ and $1/\phi$, you can probably cache the computed values and do this really quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find $n$ such that $$F_n=k$$ you could use [Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)
$$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi} = \frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt 5}
$$
$$\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \psi=\frac 1 \varphi$$ As soon as $n$ becomes large, $\psi^n$ become negligible making
$$F_n \sim  \frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt 5} $$ Now, take logarithms to get $n$.

Comment: Beat you to it. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes: Your were both beaten by some years by the answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67707/42969 :) – But who cares to search for duplicates :(

Comment: @JohnHughes. Beating the ooold man ... ! You have a nice answer $\to +1$.

Comment: You, too. (And I too am an old man...) But as Martin R points out, we're both faster at answering than at searching for duplicates. :(